# I want to change language string value using controller. How generate localisation string files dynamically?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localization

I have create files for english and german language statically in laravel rscources/lang/en and resources/lang/de folders. i want to change the string of particular lang key using my controller. how i can do ??

Comment: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization) should help you out

Answer (score 0):

Example in resources/lang/en/custom.php

```
'my_key' => 'My key'
```

Example in blade:

```
__('custom.my_key')
```

or

```
@lang('custom.my_key')
```